# Как сделать навигацию такого типа?

Tags: css

Есть обычная навигация
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью стилей сделать так,чтобы 1 и 2 кнопки были сверху,а 3 и 4 кнопки были под ними. Т.е разделить эту панель на 2 строки.

```
<ul id="pc">
        <li class="pcNav" title="Приветствие"><label for="tab1" role="button"><br><span>Приветствие</span></label></li>
        <li class="pcNav" title="Услуги"><label for="tab2" role="button"><br><span>Услуги</span></label></li>
        <li class="pcNav" title="Клиенты"><label for="tab3" role="button"><br><span></span>Клиенты</label></li>
        <li class="pcNav" title="Вакансии"><label for="tab4" role="button"><br><span>Вакансии</span></label></li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Можно ссылку на html-формат?

Comment: а где вашь панель?

Comment: Добавил html код

Answer (score 0):

Всё, что потребуется — флекс-контейнер с переносом элементов.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#pc {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pcNav {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul id="pc">
  <li class="pcNav" title="Приветствие"><label for="tab1" role="button"><br><span>Приветствие</span></label></li>
  <li class="pcNav" title="Услуги"><label for="tab2" role="button"><br><span>Услуги</span></label></li>
  <li class="pcNav" title="Клиенты"><label for="tab3" role="button"><br><span></span>Клиенты</label></li>
  <li class="pcNav" title="Вакансии"><label for="tab4" role="button"><br><span>Вакансии</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Правильно?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
#pc {
  display: block;
}

#pc > ul {
  display: block;
}

#pc > ul > li {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#pc > ul > li > ul, #pc > ul > li > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>










<div id="pc">
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
             <li class="pcNav" title="Приветствие"><label for="tab1" role="button"><br><span>Приветствие</span></label></li>

             <li class="pcNav top" title="Услуги"><label for="tab2" role="button"><br><span>Услуги</span></label></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
       <li>
        <ul>

        <li class="pcNav" title="Клиенты"><label for="tab3" role="button"><br><span></span>Клиенты</label></li>
        <li class="pcNav top" title="Вакансии"><label for="tab4" role="button"><br><span>Вакансии</span></label></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
  </ul> 
</div>



</body>
</html>
```